# menu dropdown with extended list

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I want to create smooth dropdown menu. The idea is: when clicking on orange element it will toggle black elements, and when clicking on black element it will toggle grey elements. But what i got is black element covering orange element with grey elements already toggled. I've used `display:none;` everywhere to make sure that it won't show up and.. Everything is toggled after clicking orange element. Using `.hide()` also doesn't want to help hide this elements. How can i make this black box (after `click` event) toggle below orange element and don't show grey? Also i don't know how to make grey element to not hide when someone will click on it.

```js
  $(".d").click(function(){
        $(".d ul li").slideToggle(200);
    });

$(".a").click(function(){
        $(".b").slideToggle(200);
    });
```

```css
#container
{
    width: 200px;
    height: 500px;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    overflow-y: scroll;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

ul
{
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.a, .c
{
    position: relative;
    display: none;
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    background-color: black;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.b
{
    position: relative;
    display: none;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100px;
    width: 200px;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
}

.d, .e
{
    font-size: 20px;
    position: relative;
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    background-color: orange;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
    <ul>
        <li class="d">1
            <ul>
                <li class="a"></li>
                    <ul>
                        <li class="b"></li>
                        <li class="b"></li>
                        <li class="b"></li>
                    </ul>
                <li class="c"></li>
                <li class="c"></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="d">2</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The page is getting over,so it can't scroll down so you should add element and can also use href="#id/.classname" inside element
for hide and then for looking page this can be done
    $(document).ready(function(){
       $(".a").hide();
       $(".b").hide();
       $(".d").click(function(){
            $(".d").fadeIn('fast');
        });

```
$(".a").click(function(){
        $(".b").fadeIn('fast');
    });
```